# what does initialize() mean in javafx?

Tags: javafx, initialization

I wrote some code in my project, and I found that I should put my buttonlistener in the `public void initialize()` , or I can't use the button. I don't know what the initialize() mean in javafx , why I can't change it to another method name?

This is initialize method in my code, I don't implement Initializable. So what't the mean of this in javafx?

```
public void initialize() {
    weight_number1.setOnAction(e -> number(1));
    weight_number2.setOnAction(e -> number(2));
    weight_number3.setOnAction(e -> number(3));
    weight_number4.setOnAction(e -> number(4));
    weight_number5.setOnAction(e -> number(5));
    weight_number6.setOnAction(e -> number(6));
    weight_number7.setOnAction(e -> number(7));
    weight_number8.setOnAction(e -> number(8));
    weight_number9.setOnAction(e -> number(9));
    weight_number0.setOnAction(e -> number(0));
    weight_numberCE.setOnAction(e -> symbol(1));
    weight_numberLeft.setOnAction(e -> symbol(2));
    weight_numberp.setOnAction(e -> symbol(3));

    weight_box1.setOnAction((event) -> {
        change();
        showans();
    });
    weight_box2.setOnAction((event) -> {
        change();
        showans();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `initialize()` method is used to initialize any controls, especially when it is something that can't be done from the FXML. An example of this is `setCellFactory()` and `setCellValueFactory()`. If you have nothing to initialize, then you do not need to put an `initialize()` method in your controller class.

Some people thought that they could initialize in the controller class constructor, but that is the wrong place to initialize. This is because FXML injection only occurs after the controller class has been instantiated. FXML injection occurs just before `initialize()` is being called, which makes it safe to perform initialization in `initialize()`. Initializing in constructor will give you `NullPointerException`, if you used the reference of an injected control (e.g. `@FXML private Button button`).

In JavaFX 2.0, controller classes were required to implement the `Initializable` interface if the controller has anything to initialize. If you added `initialize()` without implementing the interface, no initialization will occur.

This was changed in JavaFX 8.0. Controller classes will no longer need to implement `Initializable` interface, but you *may* still choose to do so. The only thing to take note is that you need to add the `@FXML` annotation if the `initialize()` is non-public. If the `initialize()` method is `public`, then you can just skip the annotation.

I would recommend keeping the `initialize()` method `private` (or `protected`, which is rarely useful). Keeping `initialize()` `private` makes it *less likely* for initialization to occur more than once, which could potentially cause unexpected behavior.

#### Minor Update

In case you are wondering how `initialize()` gets called when it does not implement the `Initializable` interface, it is called via  the use of Java Reflection. That is why you need to use the exact method name.

Comment: Also, when using non-`public` fields and/or methods _and_ you are using modules (Java 9+) you have to `opens` your controller's package to at least `javafx.fxml`.

Comment: @Slaw I didn't know about that, haven't had chance to upgrade from 8 because my projects used that :(